# Nested Loop in Python (dataframe)

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, nested

I am getting:

```
Syntax Error: invalid syntax
 File "<ipython-input-4-6d9421cfa070>", line 2
    for Exposure_Data_Condense['Exposure_Year'] == int(pd.DatetimeIndex(Exposure_Data_Condense['Policy_Start']).year) to int(pd.DatetimeIndex(Exposure_Data_Condense['Policy_End']).year):
```

```
for contracts in Exposure_Data_Condense:
    for Exposure_Data_Condense['Exposure_Year'] = int(pd.DatetimeIndex(Exposure_Data_Condense['Policy_Start']).year) to int(pd.DatetimeIndex(Exposure_Data_Condense['Policy_End']).year):
        for Exposure_Data_Condense['Exposure_Month'] = 1 to 12:
            Exposure_Data_Condense['Exposure_Month_Year'] = (Exposure_Data_Condense['Exposure_Year'] * 100) + Exposure_Data_Condense['Exposure_Month']
```

I am running the above code, trying to take each contract line in the Exposure_Data_Condense, and create an expanded table to include a line for each Year and Month combination from the start of each contract to the end (e.g. a contract starting in June 2021 and finishing in September 2021, should have 4 lines 202106, 202107, 202108, 202109).

My code is falling over and I am not sure why.

Note Exposure_Year and Exposure_Month columns don't currently exist in the dataframe, I am trying to create these in the for loop.

(Apologies, no doubt there are some obvious mistakes here, I am new to Python)

Comment: `range()` may help

Comment: `for variable = expression:` is not valid syntax. Loops are `for variable in expression:`

Comment: `for variable = 1 to 12:` should be `for variable in range(1, 13):`. It seems like you need to learn basic loop syntax.